# Дефолтная сортировка для списка записей в админке Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii

Имеется стандартный CRUD сгенерированный Gii

Имеется стандартный `IndexAction`

```
public function actionIndex()
{    
    $searchModel = new FilesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Необходимо реализовать дефолтную сортировку по ID в убывающем порядке.

Решил сделать так.

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    if (!array_key_exists('sort', Yii::$app->request->queryParams)){
        Yii::$app->request->setQueryParams(['sort' => '-id']);
    }

    $searchModel = new FilesSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Нормальный ли это подход, или для этих целей есть специальные настройки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция `search`, как я предполагаю возвращает `ActiveDataProvider`. Если да, то вы можете указать дефолтную сортировку так:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'id' => SORT_DESC,
        ]
    ],
]);
```